# Deploying an AppEngine Application on Compute Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Actualy I'm working on AppEngine application, and I want to use some Java Library that we can't use on with AppEngine ( like iText). So I want to know how we can deploy an App Engine application on Google Copute Engine ?
I know that's possible, I have seen it before in an event in Paris, but I can't find documentation about.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You may also be interested in the ongoing App Engine [VM Runtime TT program](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/gRZNqlQPKys/BbOHxcgYt2IJ), which lets you run Compute Engine instances as (non-sandboxed) App Engine backend instances.

Answer (score 0):

While not a usual coding question, its good to have the answer documented here.
You can use appscale on gce, see here:
http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/09/appscale-brings-choice-to-google-app-engine-developers.html